# How to set static internal IP to the GKE internal Ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I want to create a Internal Ingress for my GKE workloads. I want to know what is the annotation that I can use so that I set a static **INTERNAL** IP address/name in my ingress.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-https
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: my-cert
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "devtools.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: istio-ingressgateway-backend
    servicePort: 443
```

I understand that It will create a Ingress with Internal IP , BUt I want to set a static IP that I have already created in a region/subnet. Is it possible to do so, If yes is there any annotation for the same

Comment: Did you try [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#lb_ip)? Add the `loadBalancerIp` in the spec of your ingress. It's about K8S and not Istio, but  you can have a try! I never tried, but interested by the result of your test!

Comment: I am afraid that this will not be possible with default **Ingress** for `GKE`. As I can see you have only one path leading to `istio-ingressgateway-backend`. Does this mean you could use internal `LoadBalancer` instead of Ingress resource? If yes, here you have documentation about it: [Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Internal LoadBalancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing). You could also try to configure `nginx-ingress` with internal `LoadBalancer` as an entrypoint. Please tell which solution will suit your needs.

Comment: I have attached all my workloads with the help of Istio Virtual service. I need to use path rules to redirect traffic to different workloads. So I Type: LoadBalancer may not help in my case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### EDIT

Now you can create an Ingress resource with **Internal IP** with `GKE` by following this documentation:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Internal load balance ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress)*

Leaving the below part for an `nginx-ingress` solution with `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` that has an internal IP address.

---

---

There is a workaround for it which entails using the `nginx-ingress` controller with internal `LoadBalancer` service.

Please take a look on official documentation:

- [Cloud.google.com: Kuberentes Engine: Internal Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) - documentation used for workaround
- [Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress-nginx: Deploy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) - documentation used for workaround

Below I included an example of the workaround with explanation of taken steps.

---

### Explanation:

- It's possible to create an internal `LoadBalancer` with static IP
- `Nginx-ingress` is using `LoadBalancer` type of service as an entrypoint
- You can create an `nginx-ingress` with internal `LoadBalancer` as told in above bullet points

Steps:

- Download and modify `nginx-ingress` definition
- Run and check if `nginx-ingress-controller` service has desired static IP address
- Deploy example app and test

---

### Download and modify `nginx-ingress` definition

By default `nginx-ingress` definition from [official site](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) will have configured service of type `LoadBalancer` as an entrypoint. By default it will get an **external** IP address. You can modify/edit service definition to get an **internal** one.

Please download [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml) `YAML` and edit the part responsible for service definition below:

> ### A tip!
>
> `nginx-ingress` is also available to deploy with Helm!.

```yaml
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service   
metadata:
  annotations: # ADD THIS LINE 
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal" # ADD THIS LINE
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.4.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.1.2.99 # ADD THIS LINE 
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

Please take a specific look on part in `metadata` section:

```
  annotations: # ADD THIS LINE 
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal" # ADD THIS LINE
```

as this part will instruct `GCP` to provision an **internal** IP address

Also please take a look on:

```yaml
  loadBalancerIP: 10.156.0.99 # ADD THIS LINE
```

as this line will tell `GCP` to allocate the IP address provided.

**Please have in mind that this address should be compatible with the VPC Network that you created your cluster in.**

---

### Run and check if `nginx-ingress-controller` service has desired static IP address

After applying whole definition of `nginx-ingress` you should be able to run the:

- `kubectl get svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx`

Output of above command:

```sh
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller   LoadBalancer   10.60.6.97   10.156.0.99   80:31359/TCP,443:32413/TCP   2m59s
```

As you can see the `EXTERNAL-IP` is in fact **internal** and set to `10.156.0.99`.

You should be able to `curl` this address and get the `default-backend` of `nginx-ingress-controller`.

---

### Deploy example app and test

**This steps are optional and are only showing the process of exposing example app with mentioned `nginx-ingress`**.

`YAML` definition of `Deployment`, `Service` and `Ingress`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
  - name: hello-port
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-service
          servicePort: hello-port
```

After applying this resources you should be able to:

- `$ curl 10.156.0.99`

and be greeted with:

```sh
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: hello-app-7f46745f74-27gzh
```

Comment: Thanks, Dawid. I think this is a helpful for me. I tried to test this in my environment , but I am getting timeout error while creating Ingress. Not sure what could be the reason. Can you please let me know if this ingress can have multiple backends or it should have only one backend!

Comment: This `Ingress` can have multiple backends. Please check if you got the internal ip address on the `LoadBalancer` type of service associated with `nginx-ingress-controller`. Additionally please invoke `$ kubectl describe ingress NAME_OF_INGRESS`. You should have more information why it's failing to create there.

Comment: If I create Ingress first and nginx-controller later. It's working fine, But If I do the other way I am unable to create Ingress. I have checked the logs in nginx-controller pod. But could not notice anything.

Error from server (Timeout): error when creating "ingress.yaml": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s

Comment: It's strange behavior. I found Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527630/debugging-kubernetes-gke-timeout-issue-while-creating-ingress-with-ingress-nginx) with similar issue as yours but unfortunately without an answer. It may be a good idea to create another question for it as debugging it will divert from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the annotation
`kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: <STATIC_IP_NAME>`

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#static_ip_addressing