# How do I create an L7 Internal Ingress with IP from subnetwork

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

So we have a VPC host project on europe-west3 and a service project in europe-west1. I'm trying to create an L7 Ingress with multiple nodePort services.

The cluster I created uses a shared VPC network from the host project.
so I have 3 subnets in the shared VPC

1. myapp-node-subnets
2. myapp-pods-subnets
3. myapp-internal-lb-subnets

When I try to create the ingress. The frontend lb uses one of the IP in myapp-node-subnets but what I want is that it should use myapp-internal-lb-subnets.

-------Deployment--------

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp-web
  name: myapp-web
  namespace: myapp-dev
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp-web
    spec:
      containers:
          - name: myapp-web-dev
            image: 'docker-registry'
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            ports:
             - containerPort: 8080
```

-------Service--------

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp-web-service
  name: myapp-web-service
  namespace: myapp-dev
spec:
  ports:
  - name: myapp-web-service
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: myapp-web
  type: NodePort
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp-api-service-1
  name: myapp-api-service-1
  namespace: myapp-dev
spec:
  ports:
  - name: myapp-api-service-1
    port: 8081
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: myapp-api-1
  type: NodePort
```

-------Ingress--------

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  namespace: myapp-dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: "my-app-static-ip-1"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-web-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api-service/*
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-api-service-1
          servicePort: 8081
```

Basically I want something like this but with multiple backend services and HTTPS.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp-lb
  name: myapp-lb
  namespace: myapp-dev
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
    networking.gke.io/internal-load-balancer-allow-global-access: "true"
    networking.gke.io/internal-load-balancer-subnet: "myapp-internal-lb-subnets"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: XX.XX.XX.XX(IP I assign)
  ports:
  - name: myapp-lb
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: myapp-web
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is currently not possible. Have you considered as an alternative to create an Internal load balancer in a desired zone that will point to the `nginx-ingress` controller in your cluster? You can look in this 2 documents for more reference [gke-ilb](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing), [nginx-ingres-internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518176/how-to-set-static-internal-ip-to-the-gke-internal-ingress/62559152#62559152).