# How to configure Internal Ingress to target a specific service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I'm working on helm-charts and it should do the following:

- Allow external requests over HTTPS only (to a specific service).
- Allow internal requests over HTTP (to the same specific service).

I tried creating two ingress in which:

- The first ingress is external and accepts only HTTPS requests (which is working as expected). I used the following anntations:

```
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.citrix.com/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

- The second ingress is internal (with annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"`). This one is aimed to accept requests only from inside Minikube cluster. But it's is not working.

  - Running `nslookup <host-name>` from outside Minikube cluster returns `** server can't find <host-name>: NXDOMAIN`.
  - Running `nslookup <host-name>` from inside MInikube cluster (`minikube ssh`) returns `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`.
  - Running `curl -kv "<host-name>"` returns `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <host-name>`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For internal communication ideally, you should be using the **service name** as the hostname.

However you can crate the internal ingress it is possible, but it will give you one single IP address. Using that IP address you can call the service.

Considering you are already running the ingress controller of Nginx and service.

You can edit the ingress service and inject or update this annotation to the service.

```
annotations:  
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
```

this above line will create the **Load Balancer** service with the `internal IP` for ingress. You can create the ingress and resolve it using the curl.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62559152/5525824

still with GCP if you are not getting the static IP address you can use this snippet

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: STATIC_IP_NAME
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
```

read more at : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#static_ip_addressing